# How to use javascript in Silverstripe CMS?

Tags: javascript, silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe 3.0 CMS, and I need to include a Google Map into the CMS.

I'm following [this steps](http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/14596#post294608), and besides it's a little bit old, the [official documentation](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/javascript) uses the same methods in the current version of SilverStripe (At least it seems to be the current version documentation).

The issue is in this part of the code:

```
Behaviour.register({ 
    "#Form_EditForm" : { 
        initialize : function() { 
            this.observeMethod("PageLoaded", this.adminPageHandler); 
            this.adminPageHandler(); 
        }, 
        adminPageHandler : function() { 
            initialize(); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

First of all, Behaviour was not defined. I needed to include manually the behaviour.js file that comes within the framework. But now, I get a Type Error:

```
this.observeMethod is not a function
```

Can someone give me a hint of what can I do in order to call a javascript function when a page editor is opened in the SilverStripe CMS?

Comment: most of the js has been rewritten in version 3.0, and i guess the code fragment above is deprecated. but have you really been following the steps in the forum post you mentioned? attaching javascript via a 'Requirements' call inside 'getCMSFields' should definitly work.

Comment: ah, now i see your problem, the code in the forum post also uses this 'Behaviour.register' fragment, i'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the 'Behaviour.register' call you mention is definitly deprecated and no longer available in the core code, so the docs need an update here.

unfortunately, i couldn't find a documented way to replace this behaviour, but for now the following should work for you, based on the approach in the forum post you mentioned first hand:

find the 'initGoogleMaps.js' script added here:

```
function getCMSFields() { 
Requirements::javascript('mysite/javascript/initGoogleMaps.js');  
...
```

inside this script, remove the `Behaviour.register...` block, and move the `initialize` function *outside* document.ready (or simply remove the document.ready part), so `initialize` is globally available (you might consider renaming it).

then, add the following inside `getCMSFields`:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content', new LiteralField('js', '<script>initialize();</script>'));
```

this will ensure the `initialize` function is called every time a page's 'edit view' is rendered inside the cms.

hth

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

That worked for calling the function when browsing through the site tree. But now it doesn't work when entering using the direct link. It seems to call the function before loading the fields (Even before functions in _$(document).ready()_), so I don't have any values for latitude and longitude fields when I initialize the map.

I fixed this by temporarily calling the function when the fields are set, or in _$(documet).ready()_ otherwise. That, for now,covers entering the edit page browsing or using the direct url.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by ben,

```
LeftAndMain::require_javascript('mysite/javascript/initGoogleMaps.js')
```

is more reliable than 'include-it when needed'. Why? 
Because Silverstripe uses Ajax, it is better to load any javascript or css on the first load, so that they are ready when you go to different model admin areas within the CMS in ajax-powered environment. Not loading at the start causes inconsistency and your js, css files will not be loaded when you don't hard-load that admin area.

From documentation: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/requirements and http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/class-LeftAndMain.html

> The whole "include it when you need it" thing shows some weaknesses in
>   areas such as the CMS, where Ajax is used to load in large pieces of
>   the application, which potentially require more CSS and JavaScript to
>   be included. **At this stage, the only workaround is to ensure that
>   everything you might need is included on the first page-load.**
>
> One idea is to mention the CSS and JavaScript which should be included
>   in the header of the Ajax response, so that the client can load up
>   those scripts and stylesheets upon completion of the Ajax request.
>   This could be coded quite cleanly, but for best results we'd want to
>   extend prototype.js with our own changes to their Ajax system, so that
>   every script had consistent support for this.

By the way, the ideal place for this line is _config.php in your custom module or in mysite, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
LeftAndMain::require_javascript('mysite/javascript/initGoogleMaps.js')
```

would work much better

Comment: Why? It's important to explain what makes an answer useful or correct.