# Howto hook into 'PageLoaded' observer in SilverStripe 3?

Tags: silverstripe

I need to execute a jQuery function after a page loaded. The [docs](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/javascript#javascript-cms) told me that it would be possible to hook into the 'PageLoaded' observer.

So I tried it like shown there. I put this function

```
Behaviour.register({
    '#Form_ItemEditForm' : {
        initialize : function() {
            this.observeMethod('PageLoaded', this.pageLoaded);
            this.observeMethod('BeforeSave', this.beforeSave);
            this.pageLoaded(); // call pageload initially too.
        },
        pageLoaded : function() {
            alert("You loaded a page");
        },
        beforeSave: function() {
            alert("You clicked save");
        }
    }
});
```

into my cms.js which get's loaded in the backend. I tried it inside and outside `(function($) { .. code ..}(jQuery));` and also inside the doucment.ready function inside the first function.

I always receive the same error in my console **Uncaught ReferenceError: Behaviour is not defined**.
Where is my mystake?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use javascript in Silverstripe CMS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994174/how-to-use-javascript-in-silverstripe-cms)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have been looking at docs for 2.4, not 3.x

Version 3 and up are built using jQuery.entwine, where this from memory is old Prototype plugin stuff from 2.4, meaning of course that Behaviour is not defined, just as the error says.

The docs have recently been updated, so perhaps visit again, you might learn something new & much more helpful :)